# Bash SH - Set a new var name including in that name another var

Tags: bash, scripts, environment-variables, realtime

I just need to create an incremental var name inside a loop. The variable must use "in the var name the number of the cycle".

Example inside a loop:

```
# on Cycle=1
MyVar$Cycle=Exec$Cycle   # (equal to MyVar1=Exec1)

# on Cycle=2
MyVar$Cycle=Exec$Cycle   # (equal to MyVar2=Exec2)

# etc...
```

So how can I correctly set the var name?

In batching works easely:

```
set MyVar%Cycle%=Exec%Cycle% ...
```

But I don't know how to make it happen in Bash.

Of course tying like this `MyVar$Cycle=Exec$Cycle` do not work.

Just need to be able to set that incremental varname so I can give to them the values i may need time by time. For me, the script is working all good but the set of a new var name in real time don't.

Comment: You need to use code tags to make your post clear. See https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting for more information.

Comment: Personally I had a lot of fun with this online manual https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#Lists

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible way to solve this task is to use the command [`eval`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/23111/201297) in a way as this:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

for i in {1..5}
do
        eval "var$i"="$i"
done

# Output the result
for i in {1..5}
do
        echo -n "\$var$i : "
        eval echo "\$var$i"
done
```

Sample output:

```bsh
$ ./cycle.sh
$var1 : 1
$var2 : 2
$var3 : 3
$var4 : 4
$var5 : 5
```

---

However, I think it is better to adapt your scrip to works with [arrays](https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/06/bash-array-tutorial/) in order to avoid such magics:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

for i in {1..5}
do
        array["$i"]="$i"
done

# Output the result
for i in {1..5}
do
        echo "\$array[$i]" : "${array[$i]}"
done
```

Sample output:

```bsh
$ ./cycle.sh
$array[1] : 1
$array[2] : 2
$array[3] : 3
$array[4] : 4
$array[5] : 5
```

- Note: by default the first index within a Bash array is `[0]`, not `[1]`.

Comment: Thanks so much, you just gave me the right answer and i now can finally go ahead "Translating" a batch script into sh. Thanks

Comment: @MauSH please note that `sh` is _not_ `bash`. What `sh` is will depend on the system you are using. On Ubuntu it is a minimal shell called `dash`. This solution will not work with `sh` (or `dash`) but works with `bash`.